# Does anyone know what flower this is

Tags: identification

I’ve been trying to figure out what this flowers called it kind of reminds me of a fly trap if anyone knows please let me know [image]

Comment: Is this a plant you have encountered yourself or just photo you have found? If you could give some indication of what the rest of the plant looks like and where it grows you will be able to getter a better ID

Comment: While I don't disagree with the first answer, some lilies and irises have inflorescence very similar to orchids, so I'll second the comment above and ask for a photo of the leaves and a general size of the flower as well as where and what it's growing in.

Comment: I would say superficially similar, not very. This is definitely an orchid, probably in the genus _Paphiopedilum_ but other genera in _Cypripedioideae_ are possible.

Answer (score 1):

Such amazing plants.  These are Orchids.  I know what you are thinking about the carnivorous plants but this is an Orchid. I've been looking through the images of orchids and have not found a one I could give a species name.  Thought I'd get the conversation started.  We have incredible experts that will be able to tell you the name more closely.

We humans are the newest of our own branch; the primates.  Sunflowers are the newest or most evolved of the dicot branch of plants and Orchids are the newest and most evolved of the monocot branch.

Is this a picture you found or did you take a picture of this plant?  Tough to ID any plant just by a picture. There are Orchid officianados on our site that just might be able to get you a species and possibly a variety name.

[image: the rarest Orchid, most expensive Orchid, the Rothchild Slipper Orchid]

This is called the Rothchild Slipper Orchid
Extremely rare, out of you mind expensive!  Looks quite similar, huh?

Comment: Disagree about Orchids being most evolved. Externally they appear complicated to us but from an evolutionary perspective, there is evidence that orchids diverged around 74-86 million years ago. Grasses, on the other hand, emerged only 35 million years ago. The point at which families diverged from their ancestors is not necessarily a good indicator of how "evolved" they are - cycads are from a very ancient lineage yet many of the extant families are only 10-20 million years old.

Comment: Hey, I went to school for this and this was one of the things we were taught, albeit a while ago.  Orchids are supposedly the most evolved on the monocot branch of the plants.  I don't think that the newer 'experiments' or newer plants are the more evolved.  What do you think or know is the most evolved of the monocots?  Orchids have had a long time to perfect what worked.  I LOVE history, geology, but determining what has happened millions of years ago and keeping a lineage of fossils is very much in its infancy.

Comment: It looks like you are right; the grasses are now being heralded as 'the most evolved' on most sites.  Otherwise the sunflower and orchids were the pinnacles of their lines in the plant world.  Did you know we share 99% of our DNA with plants?  The same with all other animals.  I am heavily into researching this...perhaps it is 99% of DNA we share?  Ugh!  This means DNA then, was FIRST and we evolved around it...fascinating stuff.